# Sum Unique/Duplicate Rows Only Once

Tags: excel, sum, unique

I want to perform this `SUM` function in every row if the value in G is unique; if the value is a duplicate then fill the cell with $0

Here is my SUM formula :

```
=(SUM('Base Calculator'!$K11:$Y11)*'Base Calculator'!$I11)+'Base Calculator'!$J11)
```

The values in Column "G" aren't sorted.
The value is Column "G" is Text - e.g., "D01"

This is as far as I have gotten with experimentation:

```
=IFNA($G11=INDEX(Fact1, MATCH('Base Calculator'!$G11,UNIQUE(Fact1,0,TRUE),0),1)+1,(SUM('Base Calculator'!$K11:$Y11)*'Base Calculator'!$I11)+'Base Calculator'!$J11)
```

*Fact1 is named range of Column G.

Sample data:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: Post some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula can be used to sum up with condition of uniqueness:

```
=(SUM(A1:F1)*I1+J1)*--(COUNTIF($G$1:$G$10,G1)=1)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If I understand correctly, you need sum duplicate values too, but only once. Then a small change to the existing formula will do that:

```
=(SUM(A1:F1)*I1+J1)*--(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,G1)=1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! This formula works perfectly; however, I need to sum an instance of a duplicate once.

Comment: Post some sample data with desired result. At the moment it is difficult to understand what is really needed.

Comment: I've modified the original post with sample data. Where there is a duplicate occurrence of the value in column G that row should Total-out to 0, such that the resource is only computed once.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I paste this formula expression into excel; it does not seem to like the semicolon in COUNTIF

Comment: Yes, I forget to replace it with comma. Edited.

Comment: Question: How does the range expression in the COUNTIF work: $G$1:G1; does this only reference range of 1 cell?

Comment: For first row - yes. When you copy to 10th row, it turns to $G$1:G10 and so on.

Comment: Got it! - Thanks!